# How to measure the performance of a PC running Windows 8?

Tags: windows, performance, windows-8, adk

On Windows 7 we had a lot of third-part softwares such as [Soluto](https://www.solutotlv.com/) and [Passmark](https://www.passmark.com/),  and even Microsoft solutions, such as [xperf(Windows Performance Toolkit)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/windows-performance-toolkit-xperf). Windows 8 changed a lot of functions(boot for example), and even getting better performace, we still want to measure it to know if things are really doing good.

So, how can I measure the performance of a computer that is running Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We probably keep running third-part softwares to measure Windows 8 performance(probably Soluto and Passmark will support Windows 8 as well Windows 7). But on Microsoft solution case, there is a new performance measurement platform, where you can run assessments and test a lot of performance metrics and even funcional and reliability functions(this tool also gives you suggestions about how to solve performance problems). It is called [Windows ADK(Assessment and Deployment Kit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825343.aspx)(PS: It is public, free and it is already released):

> [Overview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28997)
>
> The Windows® Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK) is a
>   collection of tools that you can use to customize, assess, and deploy
>   Windows operating systems to new computers.
>
> Windows Deployment is for OEMs and IT professionals who customize and
>   automate the large-scale installation of Windows, such as on a factory
>   floor or across an organization. The Windows ADK supports this work
>   with the deployment tools that were previously released as part of the
>   OEM Preinstallation Kit (OPK) and the Windows Automated Installation
>   Kit (AIK).
>
> Assessments are for OEMs, IHVs, and IT professionals who measure the
>   operational characteristics of a computer, including its performance,
>   reliability, and functionality. Windows assessments are tools that
>   help you make these measurements, diagnose problems, and determine how
>   to make improvements. Windows assessments can help reduce costs by
>   identifying potential issues as you create your hardware and software
>   experiences. By using these tools, you can help ensure that the
>   hardware and software that you develop are responsive and
>   high-quality.
>
> Tools available in the Windows ADK include:
>
> - Application Compatibility Toolkit (ACT)
> - Deployment Tools
> - Windows Preinstallation Environment (Windows PE)
> - User State Migration Tool (USMT)
> - Volume Activation Management Tool (VAMT)
> - Windows Performance Toolkit (WPT)
> - Windows Assessment Toolkit
> - Windows Assessment Services
>
> Assessments are a new set of tools that measure the quality of a
>   computer, including overall performance, energy efficiency, and
>   battery consumption. The results of these assessments are used to
>   diagnose potential problems, ensuring that the hardware,  application
>   software, and drivers that you develop are responsive and have a
>   minimal impact to battery life, startup performance, and shutdown
>   time. In addition to the Assessment Toolkit, the Windows Performance
>   Toolkit lets you track detailed system information and resource usage.
>   This tool displays real-time data and diagnostics quickly and easily,
>   ensuring that you have a complete view of the system to help you tune
>   performance.
>
> Windows deployment is intended for OEMs and IT professionals who want
>   to customize and automate the installation of Windows in their
>   factories or organizations. In addition to new tools, the Windows ADK
>   includes the deployment tools that were previously released as part of
>   the Windows OEM Preinstallation Kit and the Windows Automated
>   Installation Kit.
>
> [Installing the Windows ADK:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825494.aspx)
>
> 1. Run ADK Setup from [this Microsoft website](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232339).
> 2. Select Install the Assessment and Deployment Kit to this computer.
> 3. In the Install Path box, specify the location where you want to install the Windows ADKfeatures, and then click Next.
> 4. If prompted, select whether you want to participate in the Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP), and then click Next.
> 5. To continue with Windows ADK Setup, you must accept the terms of the license agreement. To accept the terms of the license agreement,
>      click Accept.
> 6. Select the Windows ADK features that you want to install, and then click Install.

With ADK you will be able to run the following [assessments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825281.aspx):

> - [Boot Performance (Full Boot):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825507.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, and results that are associated
>     with this assessment. This assessment provides metrics like overall
>     shutdown and boot times. You can use it to compare the performance of
>     the full reboot scenario (the traditional Windows 7 boot scenario) to
>     the performance of the default shutdown and boot behaviors in Windows
>     8.
> - [Driver Certification Pre-validation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825482.aspx)  Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are
>     associated with this assessment. This assessment verifies that the
>     drivers on a running Windows operating system qualify for the Windows®
>     Certification Program.
> - [Driver Verification:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825569.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are associated with this
>     assessment. This assessment verifies that an offline Windows image or
>     a running Windows operating system contains the correct set of
>     drivers.
> - [Energy Efficiency:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825285.aspx) Describes the system requirements, job settings, results, and issues that are associated with an Energy
>     Efficiency job. An Energy Efficiency job assesses the battery life and
>     energy efficiency of a portable computer.
> - [File Handling:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825481.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, workloads, and results that are associated with this
>     assessment. This assessment simulates file operations like copying,
>     moving, compressing, uncompressing, and deleting files. It also
>     measures duration and throughput to help you evaluate the computer's
>     performance.
> - [First Boot Performance:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825290.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are associated with this
>     assessment. This assessment identifies issues that affect the time
>     that Windows takes to boot the computer and display the Start screen
>     the first time that the end user starts the computer.
> - [Internet Explorer Startup Performance:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825614.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are
>     associated with this assessment. This assessment measures the time to
>     fully render a blank page in Windows Internet Explorer®. This
>     measurement includes the load time of the IExplore.exe process and the
>     frame-creation and tab-creation intervals. It also measures the effect
>     of all extensions, add-ins, and toolbars that are installed on the
>     system. It doesn't measure any network or browsing performance.
> - [Internet Explorer Browsing Performance:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825349.aspx) Describes the system requirements, workloads, assessment settings, results, and issues that
>     are associated with this assessment. This assessment evaluates the
>     browsing experience in Internet Explorer and the capabilities of the
>     CPU and graphics hardware to identify performance issues.
> - [Media Transcoding Performance:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825545.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are
>     associated with this assessment. This assessment measures the
>     transcode duration and relative speed of changing a video file to a
>     different format or bit rate.
> - [Memory Footprint:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825365.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, and results that are associated with this
>     assessment. This assessment creates a snapshot of memory use during a
>     series of system boots. It then helps you identify ways to improve
>     performance and efficiency by optimizing memory use. You can also use
>     this assessment to compare a baseline operating system image against
>     an Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) image.
> - [Minifilter Diagnostics:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825519.aspx)  Describes the Minifilter diagnostic setting that's available in several assessments. You can use the
>     Minifilter diagnostic setting to measure the time that the computer
>     spends in minifilter operations and identify minifilter drivers that
>     are inefficient, using too much memory, or not working.
> - [On/Off Transition Performance:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825330.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are
>     associated with the Boot Performance (Fast Startup), Hibernate
>     Performance, and Standby Performance assessments. These assessments
>     measures the transition from various computer states.
> - [Photo Handling:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825458.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are associated with this
>     assessment. This assessment simulates viewing and manipulating photos,
>     and it measures responsiveness to help you evaluate the computer's
>     performance.
> - [Streaming Media Performance:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825595.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, results, and issues that are
>     associated with this assessment. This assessment streams media in
>     Internet Explorer by using video content that ranges from low
>     resolution to high resolution. It then evaluates video playback
>     quality based on the number of glitches that it detects.
> - [Windows UI Performance:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825326.aspx) Describes the system requirements, workloads, assessment settings, results, and issues that are
>     associated with this assessment. This assessment measures
>     responsiveness and rendering quality while exercising workloads that
>     simulate user activities with Windows® Runtime-based apps. These
>     activities include using search and transitioning from the Start
>     Screen to the desktop.
> - [Windows Media Player Performance and Quality:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825423.aspx) Evaluates the performance and quality of Windows Media® Player playback and is used
>     in a set of multimedia battery-life assessments.
> - [WinSAT Comprehensive:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825488.aspx) Describes the system requirements, assessment settings, and results that are associated with this
>     assessment. This assessment rates a computer's performance in several
>     system components, like CPU, memory, disk, and graphics. Windows
>     System Assessment (WinSAT) results express the capability of a
>     computer's hardware configuration in numbers by using the Windows
>     Experience Index scale of 1.0 to 9.9.
> - [Common In-Depth Analysis Issues:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825311.aspx) Describes common in-depth analysis issues that you can view in the Windows Assessment Console
>     and further analyze in Windows® Performance Analyzer (WPA).
> - [Troubleshooting Assessments:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825302.aspx) Describes common problems that cause assessments to fail.

Answer (score 0):

if installing the adk is too long there is this little exe that is portable (so it does not install)
[indice performances](https://e.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZN3wXZdKg5M4RAeMBUVpR0rV2Yf8NYBktX)

Virus Total: [Scan virus total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/e51016f1f0e839515da73795d16cb9a852f98027d8a07d85a10e090cbc4e88c5/detection/f-e51016f1f0e839515da73795d16cb9a852f98027d8a07d85a10e090cbc4e88c5-1577839142)